# Attempting to implement Dictionary class in Main

Tags: c#, forms, class, dictionary

I have the following in my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<int, FarmShop> products = new Dictionary<int, FarmShop>(); //THIS

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

On the line marked "THIS" I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'FarmShop' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have a class file called FarmShop.cs so I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: in what namespace you have this class?

Comment: What are the namespaces of `Form` and `FarmShop`? Is `FarmShop` `public`?

Comment: can you update the question with you class `FarmShop`

Comment: So does `Dictionary<int, Farm_Shop.FarmShop> products ...` work?

Comment: and in your main class, you have `using Farm_Shop;`?

Comment: you can check the `namespace` OR `access modifier` of you class

Answer (score 1):

One of few things are happening:

1. You're missing the using statement for the namespace that `FarmShop` is in, or;
2. The assembly isn't even referenced in the project the `Form` is in, or;
3. The assembly is reference, and using exists, but the assembly `FarmShop` is in isn't building, or;
4. The aforementioned are true, but `FarmShop` is in a completely different namespace and isn't `public`.

Comment: Or all those are done, but `FarmShop` is in a different namespace and not `public`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, another very possible cause. Thanks!

Comment: For entire correctness you have to combine 4 and 5. It can be in a different namespace when it's declared `public` and it doesn't have to be `public` if it's in the same namespace.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, yeah. Thanks! I need to go get another cup of coffee. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jeroen Vannevel may be right.

Make sure

- Your FarmShop class is public.
- Include the Namespace of the FarmSharp class in your codebehind page.